# Union of two files and unique in new file

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files with few similar column one, two and third column with small variation and few other columns as follows.

file 1:

```
AT1  AT22  24  1 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT2  AT24  22  0 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT3  AT23  263 3 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT4  AT28  252 6 ATAGATA ATTATAT
```

Similarly in file 2:

```
AT1  AT22  22  1 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT3  AT23  265  1 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT4  AT28  253  1 ATAGATA ATTATAT
```

The output should be Union and unique of these files with relaxation of +or -2 of the third column and if first three matches with these criteria, the fourth column has to be added from the both the files and other should be printed as usual which is like

```
AT1  AT22  24  2 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT2  AT24  22  0 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT3  AT23  263 4 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT4  AT28  252 7 ATAGATA ATTATAT
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        a[$1,$2] = $3
        val[$1,$2] = $4
        next
    } 
    ($1,$2) in a {
        for (n=$3-2; n<=$3+2; n++)
            if (a[$1,$2] == n) {
                $4+=val[$1,$2]
                break
            }
    } 
    {print}
' file2 file1
```

```
AT1 AT22 24 2 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT2  AT24  22  0 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT3 AT23 263 4 ATAGATA ATTATAT
AT4 AT28 252 7 ATAGATA ATTATAT
```

Comment: To make the columns look pretty, pipe the output through `| column -t`

Comment: I was going through your solution only in stack overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473972/how-to-compare-lines-based-on-a-column-using-awk-or-grep. But I couldn't rewrite the awk command to suit OP requirements. Can you please explain me the command?

Comment: Basically, I was trying to cat the 2 files and then use the approach that you had specified in the link that I provided :)

Comment: @glennjackman: I have tried the code and it worked well. But i am not able to find the line unique to single file in the output. This is able to print only the common lines in the two files.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you asked (as far as my test cases work)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Concatenating the 2 files and sorting entries

SRC=`cat file1 file2 | sort `
FLAG="OFF"
i=1

while read a b c d e

do
 # Need an initial array to start comparing
 if [ "$i" -eq "1"  ];then
  init_vals=( "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "$e" )
  FLAG="ON"
 else
  # Start comparing
  vals=( "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "$e" )
  if [[ ${vals[0]} ==  "${init_vals[0]}" && ${vals[1]} == "${init_vals[1]}" ]]
   then
    # First and second column are identical, checking in delta on third meet the requirements
    delta=`expr ${vals[2]} - ${init_vals[2]}`
    if [ "$delta" -ge "-2" -a "$delta" -le "2" ]
    then
      # It does, adding values on column 4 and keeping other columns
      sum_col4=`expr ${vals[3]} + ${init_vals[3]}`
      vals=( "${init_vals[0]}" "${init_vals[1]}" "${init_vals[2]}" "$sum_col4" "${init_vals[4]}" )
      #This is a tracker, we don't print result until conditions are not met
      FLAG="ON"
    else
      #Delta on column 3 is not met
      FLAG="OFF"
    fi
  else
    #Column 1 and 2 are different
    FLAG="OFF"
  fi
#    echo "$FLAG"

   if [[ $FLAG != "ON" ]];then
     echo ${init_vals[@]}
     FLAG="ON"
   fi
   init_vals=( "${vals[@]}" )

 fi
 (( i++ ))
done <<< "$SRC"
#Printing last lastline
echo ${init_vals[@]}
```

Comment: That's without awk ^^

Comment: This shows a syntax error Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi") @rMistero

Comment: Strange, it works fine with bash version 4.2.25

Comment: I realised that I had missed some test cases, the new version does what you want